# MVC EF: Discriminator field does not appear if parent class is abstract

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, migration, discriminator

I have an entity called **Product**:

```
  public abstract class Product : Entity
  {
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public long Price { get; set; }
    public abstract string Name { get; }
  }
```

I have a product called **Toy**

```
  class Toy : Product
  {
    public override string Name { get { return "Toy Product"; } }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
  }
```

So effectively, a Toy is a Product. The Product has its own properties, but it also has an abstract Property called "*Name*". The child knows its own name, so it will override it.

This seemed fine with me, but when I run Add-Migration (Since I am using EF Code-First), the *discriminator* field is missing. If remove the abstract field, and make the class non-abstract, the discriminator field appears.

Can I make a parent class abstract?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It removed the discriminator, because there's no need for it when you only have a single entity inheriting, since you can't instantiate an abstract class.

If you add another entity that inherits, like Bear:

```
public class Bear : Product
{
    public override string Name { get { return "Bear Product"; } }
    public string Fur { get; set; }
}
```

And your discriminator column will come back:

[image]

Comment: that did the job. Thanks! (will mark it as answered as soon as SO allows me to ;) )